# (Appium - JavaScript - Mocha - Promises) Returns "{state:'pending'}" instead of element text

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, appium, chai-as-promised

I am attempting to access the text within this element. Anytime I get the return value of the function or store the results in a variable, I get *"{state:'pending'}"* when printing to console. **Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing incorrectly?** Please, excuse my ignorance.

```
describe('End to End for Single Declined Applicant', function endToEnd(){
var browser;
//Initialize session
    before('Establishing Server Connection', function establishConnection(){
        browser = wd.promiseChainRemote("127.0.0.1", 4723)
        return browser.init(desired)
        .then(function goodConnection(){
            console.log("Connection Established")
        },function badConnection(){
            console.log("Connection Failed")
        });
    });

    describe('Login Page', function loginPage(){
    it('should login with valid credentials', function interactWithPage(){
        this.timeout(maxWait)
        //Check if element is available
        return browser.waitForElementById(objectRepo.loginObjects.androidUserIdField, wait, pollRate)
        .then(function enterUserId(){
            //Input text
            return browser.elementById(objectRepo.loginObjects.androidUserIdField).type(objectRepo.myInputs.userId)
        })
        .then(function getUserId(){
              //Get text from attribute
            return browser.elementById(objectRepo.loginObjects.androidUserIdField).getAttribute("text")
        })
        .then(function fulfilledPromise(){
            console.log(getUserId())
            console.log("Working")
        },function rejectedPromise(){
            //If promise in the chain is rejected
            console.log("Not Working")
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you referring to the line `console.log(getUserId())`? What is that `getUserId` function?

Comment: Yes, the getUserId() function returns the "text" attribute of the user ID element in the application. At leasts, that is my goal.

Comment: Well, apparently it rather returns a promise. You'll have to use `.then(function(text) { console.log(text); })`

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that worked. I am still a little confused about why though. Can you give me an explanation why or give me a link to some related information? I am newer to the use of promises. :)

Comment: Without seeing that `getUserId` function, I can't explain much, but for related information I can recommend https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources